# Issue with centering while keeping header in fixed position

Tags: html, css

I have a problem centering everything while keeping my header in fixed position. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="header">....</div>
   <div class="experiences">...</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
}

.header {
    background-color: #222;
    color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 130px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.experiences {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    * padding-top: 190px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 170px;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to center ? The text in experiences div ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the `left` and `right` declarations in `.header`.

The rest should already be centered (unless you use a very old version of IE...).

Comment: thank you! works great in Chrome/FF...but now not lining up in IE 8 :/ really weird. do you know of any hack i may be missing?

Comment: @aimforadamp I haven't got an IE8 at hand to test. You could put up a jsfiddle with the code in another question so other people can test it.